# Add a Right Yticks To a Plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to make a plot of sort, this is my code and the output:

```
ticks = [3500, 5000]
labels = ["\u0332P", "P\u0305"]


plt.title("Nilai Premi Optimal \n dengan Batasan")
plt.xlabel("$\it{Bargaining Power}$ \u03BB")

plt.plot(xlamda, PsiBLamda, color = "red",linestyle='dashed',label = "$\u03C8_{B} (I^*(X))$")
plt.plot(xlamda, PsiSLamda, color = "blue",linestyle='dashed', label = "$\u03C8_{S} (I^*(X))$")
plt.legend(loc="upper left")
plt.plot(xlamda, PLamda, color = "black")
plt.xlim([0, 1])
plt.ylim([3500, 7000])

plt.show()
```

[image: Plot]

The plot output is correct, however I want to add a tick on the right y axis at the 5000 point with the label P. Here is an example:

[image]

How do I code that? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Check out [secondary axes](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/secondary_axis.html):

```
ticks = [3500, 5000]
labels = ["\u0332P", "P\u0305"]


fig, ax = plt.subplots() # need the axis object

plt.title("Nilai Premi Optimal \n dengan Batasan")
plt.xlabel("$\it{Bargaining Power}$ \u03BB")

plt.plot(xlamda, PsiBLamda, color = "red",linestyle='dashed',label = "$\u03C8_{B} (I^*(X))$")
plt.plot(xlamda, PsiSLamda, color = "blue",linestyle='dashed', label = "$\u03C8_{S} (I^*(X))$")
plt.legend(loc="upper left")
plt.plot(xlamda, PLamda, color = "black")
plt.xlim([0, 1])
plt.ylim([3500, 7000])

rightax = ax.secondary_yaxis('right') # create secondary axis on the right
rightax.set_yticks(ticks) # set tick locations
rightax.set_yticklabels(labels) # set tick labels

plt.show()
```